# Changing the order of the polygon's nodes using the geometry generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, geometry-generator, nodes, order

[image]

How can I, using the geometry generator, change the order of the polygon's nodes, starting from the most northerly node in QGIS?

Comment: You mention "nodes".  What about vertices?

Comment: Why do you want to do this...? what is the background?

Comment: "Vertices" is better. Sorry, my english is not so good!

Comment: Compare the information of the polygons in qgis with information written by hand in old surveys, but the polygons do not always come with the order starting from the northernmost vertex, as is the standard here, and there are many polygons.

Comment: I think that this problem is a bit too complex to solving solely with the geometry generator. Assuming you need some automation here (to change vertice order across your dataset) PyQGIS is your best shot. You can start with the  `extract vertices` tool to get your vertices, change the order as desired, and then write this to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a recipe. In fact, I do not really exactly answer the question as I do not change order of your polygon(s) nodes but simply try to solve the issue of changing numbering of nodes according to your screenshot.

The recipe calculates the position of the northern vertex of your polygon and then use it to change numbers ordering. It avoids reconstructing the geometry by changing position of each point, just change numbering. I suppose there are way for improvements or you may encounter bugs as I did not tested extensively. Moreover, you may add more complex instructions to choose between points with same y max coordinates.

Replace in Font Marker Character(s) expression

```
@geometry_part_num
```

with

```
with_variable('new_position',
  with_variable('n_to_p', nodes_to_points(force_rhr($geometry)),
    with_variable('array_coord_y', array_foreach(
        generate_series(1, num_points(@n_to_p)), y(point_n(@n_to_p, @element))
      ),
      array_find(@array_coord_y, array_first(
          array_sort(
            @array_coord_y, ascending:=false
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  if (
    @geometry_part_num <= @new_position,
    num_points($geometry) - 1 + @geometry_part_num - @new_position,
    @geometry_part_num - (@new_position)
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi ThomasG77,

It works perfectly! Amazing!
Thank you very much!