# Number a point layer starting from the furthest north point following a linestring

Tags: qgis, sql, numbering

How can I number a point layer starting from the furthest north point following a linestring clockwise? In the image bellow I have two layers, a line layer and a point layer, and how I would like to number it. Is there a way to do it? My knowledge on virtual layers are very limited to find a solution.

[image]

Comment: What are your rules for determining, which point is the second one? Does numbering have to be consecutive along the line?

Comment: oh yeah, it has to be clockwise and yes, it has to be consecutive!

Comment: Are your points anywhere **along the line** or are they vertices of the line layer (which seems to be the case) ... ?

Comment: Are you really talking about a **line** layer (not rather a polygon layer) ? If you're working with non-closed line feature the northernmost point can be **anywhere** on the line ... how would you like to number points in that case ?

Comment: The points were vertices that I extracted from the line! It contains a "vertex_index" field but they do not follow the furthest north rule that I need. And of course this is just a test file that I created just to understand the logic behind the solution. The real line that I need to adjust has approximately 300 points.

Comment: I can't understand your statement. Linestrings can't have northernmost points? But I don't mind if the solution comes in a polygon - points structure, it's quite easy for me to transform the line in polygon in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an expression to create a new field with field-calculatot that re-counts the vertices, creating a new index, starting from the northernmost point (see at the bottom for explanation). Use this expression to create a new field named, let's say, `index_new`:

```
if (
    vertex_index < 
    aggregate( 
        @layer, 
        'max',
        vertex_index,
        $y = maximum( $y)
    ),
    vertex_index + ( aggregate (
        @layer,
        'count',
        vertex_index
    ) - aggregate ( 
            @layer, 
            'max',
            vertex_index,
            $y = maximum( $y)
    )),
    vertex_index - aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'max',
        vertex_index,
        $y = maximum( $y)
    )
)
```

Original setting - be aware that in my case, I had a closed line with identical start- and end-points, so one vertex is double:

[image]

And this is how it looks afterwards - the same vertex is double, but got two new index-numbers:

[image]

**Explanation:**
To calculate the vertex_index-no of the northernmost point, use an aggregate function. The function looks in the current layer (`@layer`)for the maximum value (`'max'`) in the field `vertex_index` but limited to the case where the y-coordinate (`$y`)corresponds (`=`) to the max. value of all y-coordinates (`maximum( $y)`):

```
aggregate( 
    @layer, 
    'max',
    vertex_index,
    $y = maximum( $y)
)
```

Than calculate the number of vertices you have, using again aggregate:

```
aggregate( 
    @layer,
    'count',
    vertex_index
)
```

Now you can combine both with an if-condition: for vertices with indices smaller than the northernmost point and for all other points.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Made another approach in a similar question but for geometry generator e.g https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388421/changing-the-order-of-the-polygons-nodes-using-the-geometry-generator-in-qgis/388564